# Spring data JPA throwing java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: X [Kotlin]

Tags: jpa, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

One of the attributes of an `Entity` was an `inline class` (an experimental feature at the time of this question). And when running a spring boot application I was getting a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3` which made no sense to me.

Turns out `3` was the number indicating the position of the attribute in my entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_entity_table")
class MyEntity(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Long = 0,

    @Column(name = "some_field")
    val someField: Int = 2,

    @Column(name = "a_second_field")
    val aSecondField: ASecondField
)

inline class ASecondField(val value: String)
```

And this was part of the stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myEntityRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3


...

Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PreferredConstructorDiscoverer$Discoverers.buildPreferredConstructor(PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.java:221)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PreferredConstructorDiscoverer$Discoverers.access$200(PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.java:89)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PreferredConstructorDiscoverer$Discoverers$2.lambda$discover$0(PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.java:161)

...
```

Answer (score -3):

The solution for that was to make my inline class (`ASecondField` in the example) a `typealias`.

So the original code was:

```
inline class ASecondField(val value: String)
```

And this was how I solved it:

```
typealias ASecondField = String
```

Of course this is not the optimal answer since I had to change the original design.