# Store Kotlin inline class to MongoDB with Spring Data

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, mapping, spring-data-mongodb, kotlin-inline-class

I'm trying to store a Kotlin's (v1.3.61) *inline class* to a MongoDB using Spring Data MongoDB (2.2.3-RELEASE), with no luck so far. This is the set up:

```
inline class UserId(@NotBlank val id: String)
```

and

```
@Document(collection = "data")
class Data(
  @Field("uid")
  val userId: UserId
)
```

Spring throws the following exception when creating its beans:

> Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1    at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PreferredConstructorDiscoverer$Discoverers.buildPreferredConstructor(PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.java:221)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PreferredConstructorDiscoverer$Discoverers.access$200(PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.java:89)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PreferredConstructorDiscoverer$Discoverers$2.lambda$discover$0(PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.java:161)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_171]   at
>   java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_171]   at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_171]   at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_171]   at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_171]   at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_171]   at
>   java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_171]   at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_171]   at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_171]   at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PreferredConstructorDiscoverer$Discoverers$2.discover(PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.java:164)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.discover(PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.java:77)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.(BasicPersistentEntity.java:105)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.BasicMongoPersistentEntity.(BasicMongoPersistentEntity.java:74)
>   ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext.createPersistentEntity(MongoMappingContext.java:91)
>   ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext.createPersistentEntity(MongoMappingContext.java:39)
>   ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:357)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:323)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:1.8.0_171]  at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.initialize(AbstractMappingContext.java:452)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractMappingContext.java:444)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]   ... 151 common frames
>   omitted

The stacktrace is quite obscure, but the exception occurs in the `PreferredConstructorDiscoverer` and the `userId` is part of the constructor, so the issue might be located there.

Next thing was checking the byte code of the `Data` class:

```
// ================net/test/Data.class
================= // class version 50.0 (50) // access flags 0x31 
public final class net/test/Data {


  @Lorg/springframework/data/mongodb/core/mapping/Document;(collection="data")

  // access flags 0x12   private final Ljava/lang/String; userId   @Lorg/springframework/data/mongodb/core/mapping/Field;(value="uid")   @Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/NotNull;() // invisible

  // access flags 0x11   public final getUserId()Ljava/lang/String;   @Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/NotNull;() // invisible    L0
    LINENUMBER 10 L0
    ALOAD 0
    GETFIELD net/test/Data.userId : Ljava/lang/String;
    ARETURN    L1
    LOCALVARIABLE this Lnet/test/Data; L0 L1 0
    MAXSTACK = 1
    MAXLOCALS = 1

  // access flags 0x2   private <init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V    L0
    LINENUMBER 7 L0
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/Object.<init> ()V
    ALOAD 0
    ALOAD 1
    PUTFIELD net/test/Data.userId : Ljava/lang/String;
    RETURN    L1
    LOCALVARIABLE this Lnet/test/Data; L0 L1 0
    LOCALVARIABLE userId Ljava/lang/String; L0 L1 1
    MAXSTACK = 2
    MAXLOCALS = 2

  // access flags 0x1001   public synthetic <init>(Ljava/lang/String;Lkotlin/jvm/internal/DefaultConstructorMarker;)V
    // annotable parameter count: 2 (visible)
    // annotable parameter count: 2 (invisible)    L0
    LINENUMBER 7 L0
    ALOAD 0
    ALOAD 1
    INVOKESPECIAL net/test/Data.<init> (Ljava/lang/String;)V
    RETURN    L1
    LOCALVARIABLE this Lnet/test/Data; L0 L1 0
    LOCALVARIABLE userId Ljava/lang/String; L0 L1 1
    LOCALVARIABLE $constructor_marker Lkotlin/jvm/internal/DefaultConstructorMarker; L0 L1 2
    MAXSTACK = 2
    MAXLOCALS = 3

  @Lkotlin/Metadata;(mv={1, 1, 16}, bv={1, 0, 3}, k=1, d1={"\u0000\u0012\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0010\u0000\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0008\u0005\u0008\u0007\u0018\u00002\u00020\u0001B\u0010\u0012\u0006\u0010\u0002\u001a\u00020\u0003\u00f8\u0001\u0000\u00a2\u0006\u0002\u0010\u0004R\u001b\u0010\u0002\u001a\u00020\u00038\u0006X\u0087\u0004\u00f8\u0001\u0000\u00a2\u0006\n\n\u0002\u0010\u0007\u001a\u0004\u0008\u0005\u0010\u0006\u0082\u0002\u0004\n\u0002\u0008\u0019\u00a8\u0006\u0008"}, d2={"Lnet/test/Data;", "", "userId", "Lnet/test/UserId;", "(Ljava/lang/String;Lkotlin/jvm/internal/DefaultConstructorMarker;)V", "getUserId", "()Ljava/lang/String;", "Ljava/lang/String;", "core"})   // compiled from: Data.kt }


// ================META-INF/core.kotlin_module =================
```

and this is the relevant line 221 of the `PreferredConstructorDiscoverer` from the Spring source:

```
String name = parameterNames == null ? null : parameterNames[i];
```

I'm a total noob in understand byte code, but one or the other might see the issue right away.

Something else I've tried was implementing two custom converters of type `org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter<UserId,String>` and vice versa. However, the bean instantiation takes place before any conversion can occur, so this seems to be irrelevant.

I'm aware that *inline classes* are still experimental in Kotlin 1.3, but maybe the actual issue lies somewhere else. Does anybody have an idea?

By the way, when changing the type from `UserId` to `String` everything works fine.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using a workaround for this, by introducing a private field.

```kotlin
inline class UserId(@NotBlank val id: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString())

@Document(collection = "data")
data class Data(
  @Transient val userId: UserId = UserId()
) {
  @Id private val idData = userId.id
}
```

But with this approach you should switch from extending CRUD-Interfaces to implement the basic operations by yourself (otherwise the ID-class makes no sense):

```kotlin
// introduce some extension functions for easier use with mongo-template
suspend inline fun <T> ReactiveMongoTemplate.saveAndAwait(entity: T) : T =
      save(entity).awaitSingle()
suspend inline fun <reified T> ReactiveMongoTemplate.findById(id: Any) : T = 
      findById(id, T::class.java).awaitSingle()

@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@Repository
internal class DataRepository(
        private val template: ReactiveMongoTemplate
) {
    suspend fun save(order: Order) : Order = template.saveAndAwait(order)
    suspend fun findById(orderId: OrderId): Order = template.findById(orderId.id)
}
```

If its worth the overhead?
Pro:

- Typed Ids
- in Mongo the id-column is still a primitive

Cons:

- Repositories get more complex

If [DATACMNS-1517](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-1517) is fixed sometime in the future, adaption should be relatively easy (mostly the implementation of repositories is removed in favour to extended interfaces).

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen [Spring data JPA throwing java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: X [Kotlin]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58784786/spring-data-jpa-throwing-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-x-kotlin)? Looks like there is no good workaround for this issue. Here is the issue for Spring Data https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-1517.

Comment: Ah, great, haven't seen this. Thank you.